# Linking segments of edges

Tags: python, image-processing, edge-detection

I have written a canny edge detection algorithm for a project. I want to know is there any method to link the broken segments of an edge, since i am getting a single edge as a conglomeration of a few segments. I am getting around 100 segments, which i am sure can be decreased with some intelligence. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a method named dynamic programming. A very good intro on this can be found on chapter 6 of Sonka's digital image processing book